# Journalctl stopped logging after being overflowed and rebooted

Tags: sshd, journalctl

My pc stopped logging since today `06:54:07`:

```
$ journalctl --verify
24af830: Invalid data object at hash entry 4203 of 233016
File corruption detected at /var/log/journal/32d0d5fb253f44a692fd0e09b4893fe2/system.journal:24af6b0 (of 41943040 bytes, 91%).
FAIL: /var/log/journal/32d0d5fb253f44a692fd0e09b4893fe2/system.journal (Bad message)
```

Some part of the `journalctl --boot=-2 -r` command output:

```
Jul 17 06:44:40 asdf sshd[7661]: ^[[0;1;39mPAM 1 more authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.5.7  user=root
Jul 17 06:44:40 asdf sshd[7661]: Disconnected from 10.0.5.7 port 41364 [preauth]
Jul 17 06:44:40 asdf sshd[7661]: Received disconnect from 10.0.5.7 port 41364:11:  [preauth]
Jul 17 06:44:40 asdf sshd[7661]: Failed password for root from 10.0.5.7 port 41364 ssh2
Jul 17 06:44:38 asdf sshd[7661]: pam_tally(sshd:auth): Tally overflowed for user root
Jul 17 06:44:37 asdf sshd[7661]: Failed password for root from 10.0.5.7 port 41364 ssh2
Jul 17 06:44:36 asdf sshd[7661]: ^[[0;1;39mpam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.5.7  user=root
Jul 17 06:44:36 asdf sshd[7661]: pam_tally(sshd:auth): Tally overflowed for user root
Jul 17 06:44:34 asdf sshd[7658]: ^[[0;1;39mPAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.5.7  user=root
Jul 17 06:44:34 asdf sshd[7658]: Disconnected from 10.0.5.7 port 33277 [preauth]
Jul 17 06:44:34 asdf sshd[7658]: Received disconnect from 10.0.5.7 port 33277:11:  [preauth]
Jul 17 06:44:34 asdf sshd[7658]: Failed password for root from 10.0.5.7 port 33277 ssh2
Jul 17 06:44:32 asdf sshd[7658]: pam_tally(sshd:auth): Tally overflowed for user root
Jul 17 06:44:32 asdf sshd[7658]: Failed password for root from 10.0.5.7 port 33277 ssh2
Jul 17 06:44:29 asdf sshd[7658]: pam_tally(sshd:auth): Tally overflowed for user root
Jul 17 06:44:29 asdf sshd[7658]: Failed password for root from 10.0.5.7 port 33277 ssh2
Jul 17 06:44:27 asdf sshd[7658]: ^[[0;1;39mpam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.5.7  user=root
Jul 17 06:44:27 asdf sshd[7658]: pam_tally(sshd:auth): Tally overflowed for user root
Jul 17 06:44:25 asdf sshd[7656]: ^[[0;1;39mPAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.0.5.7  user=root
Jul 17 06:44:25 asdf sshd[7656]: Disconnected from 10.0.5.7 port 36290 [preauth]
Jul 17 06:44:25 asdf sshd[7656]: Received disconnect from 10.0.5.7 port 36290:11:  [preauth]
Jul 17 06:44:25 asdf sshd[7656]: Failed password for root from 10.0.5.7 port 36290 ssh2
Jul 17 06:44:24 asdf sshd[7656]: pam_tally(sshd:auth): Tally overflowed for user root
```

My computer rebooted after that.

The question is:

1. is my computer compromised? if yes, how to prevent it happened again in the future without using `fail2ban`/`sshguard` because that ip (10.0.5.7) was used by all person that tries to connect to my computer (NAT'ed by the network admin)?
2. how to fix the log? I have moved the corrupted file to another directory. how to read the corrupted log for diagnosis?